# SharePoint2010 chrometype modification

Tags: front-end

I am setting up a webdesign and the headers of the webpart titles is to be designed with an image which has bowed corners. The issue is that the webparts can have dynamical widths. I used FireBug to check how the webpart headers is constructed and found 2 TD on each side of the header

```
<tr class="ms-WPHeader">
    <td align="left" class="ms-wpTdSpace">
    ...
    <td align="left" class="ms-wpTdSpace">
</tr>
```

These 2 I can use to put in the bowed corners to make the rest of the headers background dynamical in width.

So - I wondered where I can find the file which constructs the "Default" Chrome Type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could read Heather Solomons post on rounded corners. Its for SP2007 so classes are probably different, but still it might help you
http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/articles/brandsppart3a.aspx

Not sure what you mean with "file which constructs chrome type", but you define the chrome type in the web part, where you can set it to:

- Default  A border setting inherited from the part control's containing zone.
- TitleAndBorder  A title bar and a
  border.
- None  No border and no title bar.
- TitleOnly  A title bar only, without
  a border.
- BorderOnly  A border only, without a
  title bar.